# How can I create an event that recurs the Nth day from the start of a year every year?

Tags: google-calendar

For example, tomorrow is the 256th day of the year, and this day is recognized as the Programmer's Day in some countries. In this case, it's not always September 13th, because it can be September 12th for leap years, nevertheless I don't know if such case is supported in Google Calendar.

Is it possible to create such an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for possibly using an iCalendar kludge (see other [google-calendar](/questions/tagged/google-calendar) questions about unusual repeating events) there does *not* appear to be a way to do it with the Google Calendar interface.

"Daily" repeating events only let you choose up to 30 day intervals. Similarly, "Weekly" only lets you choose an interval of up to 30 weeks.

"Monthly" won't work, because even if you choose a 12-month interval, you still have to choose a day of the month (13th) or a day of the week (second Friday). And, of course, "Yearly" only lets you choose a specific date.

I think the best you'll be able to do is to make a Yearly event on September 13, and then manually move those occurrences in leap years back the the 12th.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see a way to have an event on the Nth day of the year in Microsoft Outlook, either.

Comment: I had the same idea to simulate such an event using a yearly event, but it's too fragile and cannot be consistent as it might be. Probably the Google Calendar team will add such events support in the future, who knows. :) Anyway, thank you for the reply. :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can add four separate events (September 13th for 2001, 2002, 2003 and September 12th for 2004) and make them recurring every four years. But it'll break at 2400 :) and you won't be able to edit them all at once.